# No option "I would like my site to be private, visible only to users I choose" in Privacy Settings

Tags: security, options, privacy

I am running WordPress 3.3.2 self-hosted. I used to see the option "I would like my site to be private, visible only to users I choose" under Privacy Settings but I no longer see this option. Instead, now I only see the options to make the blog visible or not visible to search engines, but no way to make it private.

I have already tried deactivating all plugins and setting to a basic theme (Twenty Eleven 1.3) to see if my plugins or theme were causing a problem, but still do not see the old option.

Any tips much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you were on WordPress.com previously, which has options that are not built in to the core of WordPress. There are various plugins out there to accomplish a similar end result, such as [Restricted Site Access](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/restricted-site-access/).

Comment: I guess you are right - sorry for my confusion, I really thought I had seen it before in my self-hosted site.

Answer (score 1):

There has a never been an option like this in core, so it must have been coming from a plugin you had previously installed. There are quite a few private site or private network themes, so I'd look for that. If you can identify a plugin that likely created that functionality, look at their changelog and see if they've recently moved their settings somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

The option label was something like this but it was intended about search engine indexing your site. So, after later version they clarified this (because some people was confused parhaps).

here is bit of code where you can redirect visitors not logged in to login screen.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_visitors_not_logged_in');

function redirect_visitors_not_logged_in(){
    $redirect_to = get_permalink();
 if(!is_user_logged_in()){
  wp_redirect(wp_login_url($redirect_to));
  exit;
 }
}
```

Now you can manually add users from dashboard. And after login they will be able to access the site. Very basic function but you get the idea :)

Answer (score 1):

There's never been a core option like that. Try [WordPress › Absolute Privacy « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/absolute-privacy/) to restrict users and anyone not registered from seeing the site at all and disabling the RSS feed to further keep search bots from indexing the site.